# Suggestions how to re-write the following Java code snippet

Tags: java

I was trying to convert this code into a more elegant or efficient way to code it.

```
final ContentSlotForPageModel rel = modelService.create(ContentSlotForPageModel.class);
rel.setUid("rel_1");
rel.setPosition("no");
rel.setCatalogVersion(catalogVersionModel);
rel.setPage(firstContentPage);
rel.setContentSlot(slot);
modelService.save(rel);

final ContentSlotForTemplateModel relTemplate = modelService.create(ContentSlotForTemplateModel.class);
relTemplate.setUid("relTemplate_1");
relTemplate.setPosition("no");
relTemplate.setCatalogVersion(catalogVersionModel);
relTemplate.setPageTemplate(template);
relTemplate.setContentSlot(slot);
modelService.save(rel);
```

Where `ContentSlotForPageModel` and `ContentSlotForTemplateModel` are subtypes of `CMSRelationModel`. So I tried to create a method that sets these attributes by using its supertype like this:

```
private void setRelationModel(final CMSRelationModel rel, final ContentSlotModel slot, final String id)
{
    rel.setUid(id);
    rel.setCatalogVersion(catalogVersionModel);

    if (rel instanceof ContentSlotForPageModel)
    {
        ((ContentSlotForPageModel) rel).setPage(firstContentPage);
        ((ContentSlotForPageModel) rel).setContentSlot(slot);
        ((ContentSlotForPageModel) rel).setPosition("no");
    }
    else if (rel instanceof ContentSlotForTemplateModel)
    {
        ((ContentSlotForTemplateModel) rel).setPageTemplate(template);
        ((ContentSlotForTemplateModel) rel).setContentSlot(slot);
        ((ContentSlotForTemplateModel) rel).setPosition("no");
    }

    modelService.save(rel);

}
```

However, many methods are not defined on CMSRelationModel and therefore I need to create a validation to make the right call. I cant define this methods on its superclass. Is there a nicer way to write this?

Thank you

Comment: May be I was not clear enough. It is not a matter of how to call the method. It is a matter of how to create the method setRelationModel more generic so I dont have to repeat: setPage, setContentSlot. and so on and skip the validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following.
No `instanceof`, strongly typed, minimisation of duplicated code.

```
private void setRelationModel(ContentSlotForPageModel rel, ContentSlotModel slot, String id) {
    rel.setPage(firstContentPage);
    rel.setContentSlot(slot);
    rel.setPosition("no");
    setCMSRelationModel(rel);
}

private void setRelationModel(ContentSlotForTemplateModel rel, ContentSlotModel slot, String id) {
    rel.setPageTemplate(template);
    rel.setContentSlot(slot);
    rel.setPosition("no");
    setCMSRelationModel(rel);
}

private void setCMSRelationModel(CMSRelationModel rel, String id) {
    rel.setUid(id);
    rel.setCatalogVersion(catalogVersionModel);
    modelService.save(rel);
}
```

I also removed `final` from the parameters to reduce "code noise".

Answer (score 0):

Could you create a new superclass in between them?

```
public abstract class SuperContentSlotModel extends CMSRelationModel{
    private String position;
    private ContentSlotModel slot;
    //...
}

class ContentSlotForPageModel extends SuperContentSlotModel{
    private int page;
    //...
}
```

Also, you could use method overloading instead of `instanceof`:

```
private void setRelationModel(final ContentSlotForPageModel rel, final ContentSlotModel slot, final String id){
    //...
}
private void setRelationModel(final ContentSlotForTemplateModel rel, final ContentSlotModel slot, final String id){
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this..

First of all, you populate the fields which are inherited from `CMSRelationModel`, then populate the fields based on your child classes such as using `instanceof` operator.

Here is sample

```
private void setRelationModel(final CMSRelationModel rel, final ContentSlotModel slot, final String id)
{
    rel.setUid(id);
    rel.setCatalogVersion(catalogVersionModel);
    rel.setContentSlot(slot); // assume this is inherited method from CMSRelationModel
    rel.setPosition("no"); // assume this is inherited method from CMSRelationModel

    if (rel instanceof ContentSlotForPageModel)
    {
        ((ContentSlotForPageModel) rel).setPage(firstContentPage);
    }
    else if (rel instanceof ContentSlotForTemplateModel)
    {
        ((ContentSlotForTemplateModel) rel).setPageTemplate(template);
    }

    modelService.save(rel);
}
```